# Why do I cannot use __repr__ data outside of a class

Tags: python, class, repr

I started Python and struggle on using `__repr__` data outside of a class. Printing the data outputs a list with lists (exactly what I wanted to do), example:
`print(test)` leads to:

```
[['Food', '-10.15', '-15.89', '-50'], ['Clothing', '-25.55'], ['Auto', '-15']]
```

My problem is:
`print(test[0])` leads to unexpected outputs, not:

```
['Food', '-10.15', '-15.89', '-50']
```

rather than some data like:

```
*************Food*************
initial deposit        1000.00
groceries               -10.15
restaurant and more foo -15.89
Transfer to Clothing    -50.00
Total: 923.96
***********Clothing***********
Transfer from Food       50.00
                        -25.55
Total:  24.45
*************Food*************
initial deposit        1000.00
groceries               -10.15
restaurant and more foo -15.89
Transfer to Clothing    -50.00
Total: 923.96
None
.***********Business***********
deposit                 900.00
                        -10.99
```

```
class Category:
  def __init__(self, category):
    self.category = category
    self.balance = 0
    self.ledger = []
  def __repr__(self):
    b = []
    b.append(self.category)
    for obj in self.ledger:
      if str(obj['amount'])[0] == "-":
        b.append(str(obj['amount']))
    return str(b)
  def __str__(self):
    lengthTop = int((30 - len(str(self.category))) / 2)
    output = "*" * lengthTop + self.category + "*" * lengthTop
    for entry in self.ledger:
      if len(entry['description']) > 23:  
        x = slice(0, 23)
        output += "\n" + entry['description'][x] + ("{:7.2f}".format(entry['amount']))
      else:
        output += ("\n" + entry['description'] + (" " * (23 - int(len(entry['description'])))) + ("{:7.2f}".format(entry['amount']))) 
    output += "\n" + "Total:" + ("{:7.2f}".format(self.balance))
    return output
  def check_funds(self, amount):
    if amount > self.balance:
      return False
    else:
      return True
  def deposit(self, amount, description=""):
    self.balance += amount
    self.ledger.append({"amount": amount, "description": description})
  def withdraw(self, amount, description=""):
    if self.check_funds(amount) == True:
      self.balance -= amount
      self.ledger.append({"amount": -amount, "description": description})
      return True
    else:
      return False
  def get_balance(self):
    return self.balance
  def transfer(self, amount, newcategory):
    if self.check_funds(amount) == True:
      self.withdraw(amount, "Transfer to " + newcategory.category)
      newcategory.deposit(amount, "Transfer from " + self.category)
      return True
    else:
      return False
def create_spend_chart(categories):
  test = categories
  print(test)
```

Comment: `print` uses `__str__`, not `__repr__`, to get a string value for its arguments. When you try to print a `list`, though, `list.__str__` itself uses `__repr__` to create strings from its elements.

Comment: `print(repr(test[0]))`